# Is it possible to add a Nav Bar to a Tabbed bar controller? Or do I put a Tabbed Bar Controller within a Nav Controller in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I know it's bad practice to have a Tabbed Bar Controller within a Nav Controller, but I would like to have the Nav Bar on top without having to add a Nav Controller to each Tabbed Item individually. Is there any work around for this.

Comment: "I would like to have the Nav Bar on top"  In general, when a user sees a Nav Bar, he/she expects it to provide typical NavigationBar functionality. If you want to display a "Nav Bar" at the top of the window when you're using Tab Bar layout/navigation, what is the Nav Bar going to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the better approach is to add a Navigation controller to each of the tabs.
In this way every tab can have connection to other controller.
I created a sample project here: https://github.com/TeamPacMan/TabedNavigationController.
Give it a look.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think that is the better root too.

Comment: One last thing. The other About VC (Tabbed Item) has no need for a Nav Controller but I still want the same design with regards to the Nav Bar (I don't have the Title in the Tabbed Bar, but rather in the Nav Bar). I have added swipe gestures and it's very "unsmooth" when swiping from a VC with a Nav Bar to one without. Would the only way around this be designing and adding a similar Bar that a Nav Bar produces?

Answer (score 0):

Use This Image For Reference

[You Can Do Something Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98QVV.png)